# Use External IP while in my Network (Apache server)

Tags: port-forwarding

Currently I have opened port 80 and 443 for 192.168.2.40 (My Apache Server) and when I am not in my network, my external IP (68.237.174.32) correctly resolves to the Apache server.

I have a Linksys EA2700 router.

When in my network, I can only use the internal IP address to reach it (192.168.2.40). If I attempt to go to 68.237.174.32 while on my wifi network, I am given a blank page.

What changes do I need to make so that the external IP works while I am in my network?

I want 68.237.174.32 to resolve to 192.168.2.40 while I am within my network.

Note: NAT is enabled.

Thank you!

Comment: or superuser.com/questions/803385/port-forwarding-how-to-access-from-external-ip?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

Can you enable Local Loopback NAT on modem/router? The NAT on your modem/router if preventing you from accessing your external IP port forwarding from within you LAN.

Adding HOSTS entry is another option.

Comment: Under my Advanced Routing settings, I have "NAT" enabled. I have a Linksys EA2700 router. I think that would mean I have it enabled, right? Also: By adding HOSTS, do you mean editing the host files on individual devices? If so, it would not work since we have iPhones in the network.

Comment: No HOSTS will not work for you, has to be done on every device and is not a tidy solution. The problem is that NAT will not allow local LAN to go out to your external IP and back in to LAN again. You need to be able to 'enable' an additional feature called "Local Loopback NAT" or Reflection or "Hairpin NAT" ... it is quite likely your modem does NOT support this.

Comment: Have you tried setting an external domain address for your external IP?

Comment: I see! I'll search around my Router Settings for "Local Loopback NAT" and "Hairpin NAT." I'm feeling pessimistic about the Linksys ea2700. It probably does not support this.     I currently have owncloud.anwsol.com pointing to my external IP address which also does not work while in my network. =(